# Script closes after specific line, 'composer install'

Tags: windows, laravel, batch-file

I'm working on a script to start the laravel project from a github repo.

```
start cmd /c "mysqld" mysqld --log_syslog=0 --console
cd ./html/BackendAPI/
composer install  --no-interaction
php artisan key:generate  --no-interaction
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed  --no-interaction
```

But the console closes after the `composer install`.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Can you provide the output log?

Comment: @Christoffer What I mean is that the console closes, I tried with pause after composer install but it closes anyways.

Comment: Try 'call composer install  --no-interaction' instead

Comment: …is `composer` not a `.phar` file, _(php archive)_? If it is then I may advise creating a `composer.cmd` file along side it with content similar to `@php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*`, and then use `Call composer install --no-interaction`, depending upon your `%PATHEXT%` content; or to be safe `Call composer.cmd install --no-interaction`. This also assumes that your installation included adding the location of `composer` to `%PATH%`.

Comment: With call it's working ty guys

Answer (score 0):

Use call to run composer install command

Like below

```
start cmd /c "mysqld" mysqld --log_syslog=0 --console
cd ./html/BackendAPI/
call composer install  --no-interaction
php artisan key:generate  --no-interaction
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed  --no-interaction
```